# What professional installs dryer vents?

Tags: dryer, vent

I need to relocate our dryer vent. It goes behind the wall and to the roof. With our new stacking machine, we need to move a few feet. For the life if me, I can't figure out who to hire to do it. I want to make sure it's to code. Any ideas?

Comment: How many feet is "*a few feet*"?  What does the connection look like now?

Comment: licensed contractor or a handyman would be my recomendation licensed handyman is usually cheaper. HVAC would probably be the most expensive route and the contractor or handyman do more wall repairs to finish the job better in my option.

Answer (score 1):

you can call a HVAC company, you can also call a general contractor. Going out on a limb here, there is a good chance it already isn't to code, many many many installations aren't. As a matter of fact, it is advisable and recommended the dryer piping get cleaned out once to twice a year (if you use it a lot, twice).